# Wordpress Admin Page Redirecting to Subdomain

Tags: wp-admin

My Wordpress website admin page http://example.com/wp-admin keeps redirecting me to the subdomain I created when adding the site to my CPanel. I have to use wp-login.php when accessing the Wordpress admin dashboard.

I'm using BlueHost as my hosting provider. They can't seem to help me figure this out. I have to use wp-login.php when accessing the Wordpress admin dashboard.

Any help is appreciated.

- A

Comment: what do you mean to the subdomain? `http://subdomain.example.com/wp-admin` ?

Comment: @DavidLee I mean it redirects to http://example.primarydomain.com/wp-admin/

A subdomain is created when adding a domain to CPanel.

Comment: can you edit your question and elaborate more please, with steps of what are you doing, because you say "keeps redirecting me to the subdomain I created" but also say "A subdomain is created when adding a domain" also its a single WP install or MultiSite

Comment: Sure. Ok, so when you create a hosting account, you are supposed to add a domain name as the "primary" domain name for the hosting account. Any domain names you add moving forward are assigned to the CPanel account as subdomains. Does that explain it? Thanks.

Comment: So, the Wordpress site I'm referring to in my question is a subdomain assigned to the account. And when I try to access the wp-admin page for that site, it redirects me to http://example.primarydomain.com/wp-admin/

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I hope you can help me find a solution.

Comment: "Any domain names you add moving forward are assigned to the CPanel account as subdomains." you account supports multiple domains? because that sounds just like you can have only one (primary), then have subdomains

Comment: "the Wordpress site I'm referring to in my question is a subdomain assigned to the account" you mean Wordpress is installed each time a subdomain is added?

Comment: it sounds like WP was installed under the subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Add the indicated line to your .htaccess and all should be fixed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
**RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?YourDomain\.com$ [nc]**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```